# How to combine FromBody and FromForm BindingSource in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I've created a fresh ASP.NET Core 2.1 API project, with a `Data` dto class and this controller action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult<Data> Post([FromForm][FromBody] Data data)
{
    return new ActionResult<Data>(data);
}
```

```
public class Data
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Txt { get; set; }
}
```

It should echo the data back to the user, nothing fancy. However, only one of the two attributes works, depending on the order.

Here's the test requests:

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:5000/api/values \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  -d 'id=qwer567&txt=text%20from%20x-www-form-urlencoded'
```

and

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:5000/api/values \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{
    "id": "abc123",
    "txt": "text from application/json"
}'
```

I've tried several approaches, all to no avail:

- Creating a custom child `BindingSource`, but that's only metadata it seems.
- Using an attribute `[CompositeBindingSource(...)]`, but the constructor is private and this might not be intended usage
- Creating an `IModelBinder` and provider for this, but (1) I might only want this on specific controller actions and (2) it's really a lot of work seemingly to get the two inner model binders (for Body and FormCollection)

So, what is the correct way to combine `FromForm` and `FromBody` (or I guess any other combination of sources) attributes into one?

To clarify the reason behind this, and to explain why my question is not a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51430923/419956): I want to *know* how to have the same URI / Route to support both different types of sending data. (Even though perhaps to some folks' taste, including possibly my own, different routes/uris might be more appropriate.)

Comment: May I ask why you would want to do that? I just tried bc maybe I thought you can just leave out both attributes and it would work. Form request only works with [FromForm] while json-request works without [FromBody].

Comment: Because I want to offer consumers both ways of calling the API. (At least, I _think_ that's the reason. Someone else asked me this same question, and at this point I just want to know for the sake of knowing :D). PS. If I recall correctly, leaving out `[FromBody]` works in recent versions because it is assumed by convention.

Comment: @Jeroen: You are correct, but only when the `[ApiController]` attribute is applied to the controller. For controllers decorated with that attribute, a class param is assumed to be `[FromBody]` implicitly. However, in that scenario, `[FromForm]` needs to be applied if you actually want it that way, instead.

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51430923/posting-form-data-to-mvc-core-api/51431788#51431788) (it's mine) might help with an explanation of the `[ApiController]` approach and splitting out the two actions that @ChrisPratt has suggested in his answer (I've tagged it as a *possible* dupe).

Comment: Thx @KirkLarkin for your response, your link and the answer by Chris are helpful. I don't think it's a duplicate though, somewhat indicated by the fact that Chris' answer ("You cannot.", plus a workaround to get a the same effect as a combined attribute) wouldn't be applicable to the other question. - PS. I'm not giving up yet either, and will investigate further to see if I can get an answer to my own question after all.

Comment: See my edit at the bottom of the question explaining why I don't think it's a duplicate.

Answer (score 14):

You might be able to achieve what you're looking for with a custom [`IActionConstraint`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.1#understanding-iactionconstraint):

> Conceptually, IActionConstraint is a form of overloading, but instead of overloading methods with the same name, it's overloading between actions that match the same URL.

I've had a bit of a play with this and have come up with the following `IActionConstraint` implementation:

```
public class FormContentTypeAttribute : Attribute, IActionConstraint
{
    public int Order => 0;

    public bool Accept(ActionConstraintContext ctx) =>
        ctx.RouteContext.HttpContext.Request.HasFormContentType;
}
```

As you can see, it's very simple - it's just checking whether or not the incoming HTTP request is of a form content-type. In order to use this, you can attribute the relevant action. Here's a complete example that also includes the idea suggested in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51430923/posting-form-data-to-mvc-core-api/51431788#51431788), but using your action:

```
[HttpPost]
[FormContentType]
public ActionResult<Data> PostFromForm([FromForm] Data data) =>
    DoPost(data);

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult<Data> PostFromBody([FromBody] Data data) =>
    DoPost(data);

private ActionResult<Data> DoPost(Data data) =>
    new ActionResult<Data>(data);
```

`[FromBody]` is optional above, due to the  use of `[ApiController]`, but I've included it to be explicit in the example.

Also from the docs:

> ...an action with an IActionConstraint is always considered better than an action without.

This means that when the incoming request is not of a form content-type, the `FormContentType` attribute I've shown will exclude that particular action and therefore use the `PostFromBody`. Otherwise, if it *is* of a form content-type, the `PostFromForm` action will win due to it being "considered better".

I've tested this at a fairly basic level and it does appear to do what you're looking for. There may be cases where it doesn't quite fit so I'd encourage you to have a play with it and see where you can go with it. I fully expect that you may find a case where it falls over completely, but it's an interesting idea to explore nonetheless.

Finally, if you don't like having to use an attribute, it is possible to configure a convention that could e.g. use reflection to find actions with a `[FromForm]` attribute and automatically add the constraint. There are more details in this excellent [post](https://www.strathweb.com/2017/06/using-iactionconstraints-in-asp-net-core-mvc/) on the topic.

Comment: I love when the accepted answer says you cannot do something and the answer below it tells you how to do it.

Answer (score 8):

I love the solution proposed in the accepted answer, and even used it for a while, but now we have the `[Consumes]` attribute.

**And you can even map the two to the same route URL** which is great news.

```cs
[HttpPost]
[Route("/api/Post")] //same route but different "Consumes"
[Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")]
public ActionResult Post([FromForm] Data data)
{
    DoStuff();
}

[HttpPost]
[Route("/api/Post")] //same route but different "Consumes"
[Consumes("application/json")]
public ActionResult PostJson([FromBody] Data data)
{
    Post(data); //just call the other action method
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#define-supported-request-content-types-with-the-consumes-attribute

Answer (score 6):

You cannot. An action can only accept one or the other. To get around this, you can simply create multiple actions, one with `[FromBody]` and one without. They'll of course need separate routes as well, since the presence of an attribute is not enough to distinguish overloads. However, you can factor out the body of your action into a private method that both actions can utilize, to at least keep things DRY.

Answer (score 1):

nuget package Toycloud.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.BodyAndFormBinding
should fits your needs

[github](https://github.com/shamork/Toycloud.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.BodyAndFormBinding)