# Make Swagger-UI show a form for operation parameter types

Tags: .net, asp.net-core-webapi, swagger-ui, openapi

I've set up a web API with ASP.NET Core and Swashbuckle. All my controllers and actions show up correctly and I can try them out. For simple action parameters like a string, a form is displayed and I can enter each parameter value in that form before sending the request.

but if the action expects a class instance (data structure) as parameter, I'm left completely alone with the JSON request body. There's no form for the class properties, just a textbox where I can edit my JSON body to send. The operation is described as having no parameters (which is wrong) and the used class is described below in the Schemas section with description texts and all properties.

What do I need to change to make swagger-ui pick up that action parameter and show me a form with all its type properties before sending a request?

Answer (score 1):

> but if the action expects a class instance (data structure) as parameter, I'm left completely alone with the JSON request body. There's no form for the class properties, just a textbox where I can edit my JSON body to send. The operation is described as having no parameters (which is wrong) and the used class is described below in the Schemas section with description texts and all properties.

Yep, that's how Swagger UI handles JSON requests.

> What do I need to change to make swagger-ui pick up that action parameter and show me a form with all its type properties before sending a request?

You can either change your controllers to accept form data (`application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data`) instead of JSON, or wait until Swagger UI implements a form-style editor for JSON requests (refer to [this feature request](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/2771)).

Comment: I added the accepted type with the `[Consumes]` attribute, now I can select it and get the input form for these types. But I must decide whether my action reads the parameter `[FromBody]` (only works with json) or `[FromForm]` (only works with form). I cannot make my action accept both. Any idea? Otherwise, I cannot use this solution and just have to accept swagger-ui's lack of feature.

Comment: @ygoe [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51673361/113116) suggests some workarounds for combining `FromForm` and `FromBody`.

Comment: Thank you, the link to the GitHub project over there did help me. (At least the API works, but OpenAPI docs created with Swashbuckle can't handle it yet.)