# Razor Page POST form data to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have developed a very simple web app in .NET Core 2.2 using the WebAPI template. I have been able to successfully test my endpoints using Postman and would like to add a simple frontend using the already available Razor Pages (.cshtml)

**Problem:**
I cannot successfully hit my controller endpoint using my razor page. I have tried decorating my endpoint with/without "[FromBody]".

My chrome debugger catches the following transaction: 
[image: Registration Form]
[image: Error]

Error on Webpage:

```
{"type":"https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.13","title":"Unsupported Media Type","status":415,"traceId":"0HLSP5DVTEH9B:00000008"}
```

Output says that the route was matched:
[image: output]

**Code:**

I have the following razor page:
**Registration.cshtml**

```
@page
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@model RegistrationModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Registration";
}
<h2>@ViewData["Title"]</h2>

@{
    using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "Registration", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        <label>Username</label>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Username)

        <br />

        <label>Password</label>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Password)

        <br />

        <label>Role</label>
        <label>
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Role, "0")
            1
        </label>
        <label>
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Role, "1")
            2
        </label>

        <br />

        <input type="submit" value="Register" />
    }
}
```

**Registration.cshtml.cs**

```
namespace RandomContent.Pages
{
    public class RegistrationModel : PageModel
    {
        public string Message { get; set; }

        public void OnGet()
        {
            Message = "Fill out the form below to be registered with the application.";
        }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "User name")]
        public string Username { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Password")]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Role")]
        public Role Role { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
namespace RandomContent.Controllers
{
    [Authorize]
    [ApiController]
    [Route("Registration")]
    public class RegistrationController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IRegistrationService _registrationService;

        public RegistrationController(IRegistrationService registrationService)
        {
            _registrationService = registrationService;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a new user
        /// Will return a bad request if the user could not be added to the db
        /// or the user already exists
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="userParam"></param>
        /// <param name="returnUrl"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("Register")]
        public IActionResult Register(RegistrationModel userParam)
        {
            //Validations
            if (!Enum.IsDefined(typeof(Role), userParam.Role))
                return BadRequest("Must select valid Role for user");
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(userParam.Username))
                return BadRequest("Must enter a username");
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(userParam.Password))
                return BadRequest("Must enter a password");

            //Register user
            var user = _registrationService.Register(userParam);
            if (user != null) return Ok(user);
            return BadRequest("Could not create user profile. They username may have been taken, or something else happened.");
        }

    }
}
```

**Question:** How can I successfully post my form data into my controller? I can't even debug into my controller unless I send my request from postman.

The full project can be found on Github: https://github.com/bestfriendkumar/RandomContent

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Posting form data to MVC Core API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51430923/posting-form-data-to-mvc-core-api)

Answer (score 0):

Try using [FromForm] like this Register([FromForm] RegistrationModel userParam)