# Upload file and primitive type to Web Api with ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, api, asp.net-core

I am currently trying to upload an Image file together with a string with ajax to an Asp.Net Core Api with no luck.

I looked at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects
and thought it would be easy to send both an Image file and a string together in a FormData object, but only the Image is received.

In javascript I am appending the data and sending it with an ajax post:

```
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("code", "123");
    formData.append("userFile", document.querySelector("#imgInput").files[0]);

    $.ajax({
        async: true,
        type: "post",
        data: formData,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        url: "https://localhost:22333/api/postmethod",
        success: function (data, response, jqXHR) {
            console.log(response);
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, response, errorThrown) {

        }
    });
```

And in Asp.Net Core the method is:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("postmethod")]
    public async Task PostMethod(IFormFile code, IFormFile userFile)
```

I have tried setting the `code` parameter to both IFormFile and string, but nothing happens. The userFile parameter is always set correctly to the Image file, which makes me wonder what I am doing wrong when uploading the `code` string.

TLDR: 
Can't upload both a image file and string with ajax call to Asp.Net Core 3.1 Api.

Is there a better way to upload the files and parameter?

Comment: Will take a look and try if might solve the issue! :)

Comment: Apologies for the confusion my initial comment caused. I forgot you have to use a complex object (multiple values, but one singular parameter). Hopefully the answer helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically there are 2 problems here. One, you cannot specify more than one parameter. Straight from the [WebAPI documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-3.1):

> When an action has more than one parameter bound from the request body, an exception is thrown.

However, instead we can just make a complex object here. You will want to do some reading on viewmodels/DTOs if you havent, but to keep things simple we can just use a model here.

Secondly, the reason why the IFormFile would bind but not the string has to do with the inferred data sources in the same documentation. [FromForm] was inferred for IFormFile but not string (nor the Image type here, either). Adding [FromForm] here tells the action to bind from the form data.

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("postmethod")]
    public async Task PostMethod([FromForm]Image image)
```

An example if you wanted to make a form to submit to this api:
HTML (must specify enctype):

```
@model .../Image
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="imageForm">
    @Html.Editorfor(m => m.Code)
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.File)
    <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

JQuery:

```
    $("#imageForm").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            data: new FormData(this),
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            url: "api/postmethod",
            success: function (data, response, jqXHR) {
                alert("Success.");
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, response, errorThrown) {
                alert("Error.")
            }
        });
    })
```

This is just assuming you want that form, again remember that this will not work similarly with JSON. You can read more about this question at similar ones [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51430923/posting-form-data-to-mvc-core-api) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51892706/asp-net-core-web-api-file-upload-and-form-data-multiple-parameter-passing-to-m):

Comment: Amazing, you are 100% correct. I have read through the documents some time before, but I not sure if I took note of that aspect. Everything worked perfectly once I created a class with the desired properties and used it as parameter! Thank you so much! :)